# Flyway not able find placeholder from conf file

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I am using flyway 3.2.1 and want to use a placeholder replacement in my migration scripts to replace the schema name as per the environment

when I pass the placeholder from CLI as

```
initialize flyway:migrate -Dflyway.outOfOrder=true -DskipTests -Dflyway.placeholders.schemaName=testDbName
```

the migrations work fine.

but when I try to do the same using flyawy.conf file I get the exception as 
FlywayException: No value provided for placeholder expressions: ${schemaName}

I have tried passing the file path and name in CLI

`initialize flyway:migrate -Dflyway.outOfOrder=true -DskipTests -Dflyway.configFiles=/resource/flyway.conf`

I have also tried to place the config file in the same directory as of migration script resources/db/migration but I get the same exception

property in config file
`flyway.placeholders.schemaName=testDbName`

and sql is

```
insert into ${schemaName}.employee_department(emp_id,dept_id) values(123,87);
```

am I missing something about the file location or not passing the path properly?

Comment: whoever marked it not useful can you please state why? what part of the question makes you determine not enough research haven't been done from my side?

Answer (score 0):

used maven property to provide conf file path

```
<configFile>src/main/resources/flyway.conf</configFile>
```